# Java takeWhile statefulness

Tags: java

I'm writing a parser for a programming language, and I was thinking Java's takeWhile method might be perfect for grouping the lexical tokens into structures. As an example case, to get a stream of tokens representing a brace-delimited code block, I could write:

```
stream.dropWhile(t -> !t.equals("{")).takeWhile(t -> !t.equals("}")))
```

…Except, obviously that wouldn't work if the block in question had nested blocks, such as a function declaration. In a more imperative style, I might do this after the opening brace:

```
assert(openCurlyToken.equals("{");
List blockTokens = new ArrayList<String>();
blockTokens.add(openCurlyToken);
String token;
int braceLevel = 1;
while (braceLevel > 0) {
  token = nextToken();
       if (token.equals("{")) braceLevel++;
  else if (token.equals("}")) braceLevel--;
  blockTokens.add(t);
}
return blockTokens;
```

Kinda ugly, kinda verbose. What I'm hoping is there is a more concise way to do this kind of computation using Streams?

Comment: Please show the full loop in your second snippet. It's hard to compare the stream to the loop if they aren't at the same level.

Comment: I added the omitted code to the second example.

Comment: can you please show us an input output example please It hard to understand what is `Token`, `nextToken()`, `tokenMatches` ...

Comment: It's not terribly important what a Token is, aside from the fact that they're String comparable. (Their other role is being compared against some enums.) To make this clearer I replaced Token with String in the code examples above. nextToken simply reads a token from the input

Comment: See also: http://www.antlr.org/